# add a link next to the search button?

Tags: search, forms

I like to add a "help tips" link next to the search button. I made some changes on the "search-block-form.tpl.php" (see below) but it does not show on the search result page.

Some documentation on the web suggests using function hook_form_alter to make the changes. Thank you in advance

```
<div>
  <?php if (empty($variables['form']['#block']->subject)): ?>
    <h2 class="element-invisible"><?php print t('Search form'); ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $search_form; ?>
  <a class="h_tips" href="help_tips">help_tips</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I presume that code is from `search-block-form.tpl.php`? Are you sure it's using that exact block though? Have you cleared your caches after modifying the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['help_link'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<a class="h_tips" href="help_tips">help_tips</a>',
    );
  }
}
```

That should do the work, but I am not sure if the id 'search_block_form' the right one is.
If you don't have any custom module, just place this code into your current template's template.php, replace MODULENAME with templatename, save and clear cache.

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', after copy the code below into  current template.php, 
function search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['help_link'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<a class="h_tips" href="help_tips">help_tips</a>',
    )
  }
}

Comment: Works only for the **form id=search_block_form**. I wanted to show under search result page, **id=search-form**. I tried to updated the code with '$form_id == "search-form"'  and still would not show. Do you know why? I just added a screenshot for both forms.

Comment: try "search_form" instead of "search-form"